# Codeigniter post not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

It is my first time to use codeigniter in building my school project.

Let me go straight.

I can get my POST request except for the form_upload();

This is my sample FORM:

```
<?php
echo form_open('admin/test_upload');
    echo form_input(array('name' => 'title'));?><br/><?
    echo form_upload(array('name' => 'file'));
    echo form_submit(array('name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'submit'));
echo form_close();
?>
```

This is my CONTROLLER:

```
function test_upload(){
    $data['header'] = "TEST UPLOAD";
    var_dump($_POST) ; //basically, this is function echoes back the post array.
    $this->load->view('admin/dashboard_view', $data);
}
```

This is the Output

```
array(2) {
["title"]=>
string(3) "asd"
["submit"]=>
string(6) "submit"
}

//The ["file"] is missing.... wHAT!?>
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File uploads need to have an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in their form tag, so you should be using this to open the form:

```
echo form_open_multipart('admin/test_upload');
```

Also, as the others have mentioned, the uploaded files will be in `$_FILES` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: ok so how can i retrieve this request? can i use $this->input->post('file'); ?

Comment: You will use `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` to get the path to the temporary uploaded file, which you can then copy to your server or do whatever.  `$_FILES['file']['name']` will include the original path of the uploaded file.  There's a lot more detailed information in [the docs on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the wrong superglobal (`$_POST`). Check `$_FILES` and make sure that the form's `enctype` is "multipart/data".